# Understanding foreach with pyspark structured streaming

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to figure out how to apply `foreach` to the word count example in `pyspark`, because in my use case I need to be able to write to multiple sources. However, the `foreach` class does not seem to actually ever execute, and no file ever gets created.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, split
import os
import uuid
import tempfile


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Struct-stream').getOrCreate()

lines = spark \
        .readStream \
        .format('socket') \
        .option('host', 'localhost') \
        .option('port', 9999) \
        .load()

words = lines.select(
   explode(
       split(lines.value, " ")
   ).alias("word")
)

wordCounts = words.groupBy("word").count()

open_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
process_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()

class Writer:

    open_dir = open_dir
    process_dir = process_dir

    def open(self, partition_id, epoch_id):
        with open(os.path.join(self.open_dir, str(uuid.uuid4())), 'w') as f:
            f.write("%s\n" % str({'partition_id': partition_id, 'epoch': epoch_id}))
        return True

    def process(self, row):
        with open(os.path.join(self.process_dir, str(uuid.uuid4())), 'w') as f:
            f.write("%s\n" % str({'value': 'text'}))


query = wordCounts \
        .writeStream \
        .foreach(Writer()) \
        .outputMode('complete') \
        .format('console') \
        .start()


query.awaitTermination()
```

I'm trying to understand why no file ever gets written, or if the Writer class ever actually gets executed.

Comment: `foreach` is a way to apply a function to each partition, you are trying to apply a class to it that does not even take any parameters to begin with

Comment: Hey @aws_apprentice, check out this link: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#foreach. I'm just trying to follow the documentation.